# How can I code this awesome glowing border effect with CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

This form has an awesome effect when you focus on one of its fields:

http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/panel/demo/

Any clues on how I can recreate this? Here are a few of my observations:

- I see they have a giant colorful
  image here:
  http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/panel/demo/lib/img/form/map/rmap.jpg
- When you focus on the form the color seems to fade in (and fades away on blur)
- I don't know how they are getting the soft edge (glow) using the source image they have
- I don't know how they are panning the colorful image across the border infinitely
- The markup seems pretty messy; ideally I'd want a simpler solution than what they have
- [This one](http://kaylarose.github.com/Glowform/) is a clone made all with CSS3, but I don't like how the outer glow doesn't stay uniform

Comment: Cool effects but : `* Disclaimer: This is meant as a CSS3 tech demo, not a best practices tutorial.`

Comment: @Ibu: is there already a best practice for animating a form's border with rainbows? It's not going to show up without the proper browser support, which is normal and standard browser degradation. What exactly does "not best practice" mean in this situation? More importantly, who cares? I don't mean this to be negative, I'm just really having trouble understanding where you're coming from.

Comment: eating lots of process resources is not best practice @Jordan, not to be negative but thats where i come from

Comment: @Ibu: I'm seeing 4% CPU load when I open that page. My computer's reasonably fast, but is that truly a concern? To reduce resources they could easily use a smaller image, since there's no need for a 3000x900 one. Define "lots of process resources". Computers are meant to be used; there's no reason to be scared of CPU usage, as long as it's not monopolizing or pegging your box.

Comment: lol, you are definitely right @Jordan. Since you have a fast computer

Comment: @Ibu I'm just trying to understand what you've said. So far you've provided vague terminology: "best practices" and "lots of resources". I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want you to provide actual evidence behind what you're saying, rather than pushing people away from doing new and cool things because of hearsay on the internet. FWIW I have a C2D @ 2.5ghz/proc, and it's about 2 years old. As a comparison, loading Facebook uses 6%.

Comment: yeah i rather not add useless content to this very interesting post. Instead of trying to argue maybe you should ask your self why the own people who made the css tutorial wrote this [Disclaimer](http://kaylarose.github.com/Glowform/) on their website. Don't you think so? now good day to you :)

Comment: @Ibu: no, I don't think so. I think when something has wording as strong as "best practice", that it should be vetted and explained, rather than just bandied around and accepted without any thought. I don't know how strong of a developer KaylaRose is, so I'm not going to simply accept one person's word as gold simply because she says so. My point remains: explain why this is not best practice, and provide evidence for the arrival at your explanation. If anything, you should say it's bad practice simply for the UI distraction when you just want someone to fill out your very important form.

Answer (score 8):

The color changing action occurs as the position of rmap.jpg (the very large colorful image) is animated.  There is an .png with alpha-transparencies which acts as matte over rmap.jpg, creating the nice soft color transition.  The animation is handled using jQuery.

[Peter Schmalfeldt](http://www.manifestinteractive.com/) created a [demo](http://www.manifestinteractive.com/usenet/login/) which is also [downloadable](http://www.manifestinteractive.com/usenet/login.zip).

Answer (score 4):

The soft edge that you see is actually a transparent image named `content-gradient.png` inside an `<img/>` tag.

So the big colorful image comes beneath this PNG and creates an illusion of soft glowing edges.

If you have Google Chrome or Firefox with Firebug, you can "inspect" the DOM to see how it works. You'll notice that the colorful image's background position is being changed at runtime which can be done using a loop with jQuery or another Javascript library.

The [js.php?page=login](http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/panel/demo/lib/js/js.php?page=login) resource is probably what's taking care of the logic.

Comment: PHP is server-side: it cannot run a loop on the client. Also, jQuery isn't a language: it's a library.