# Animated glowing border using CSS/ JS?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to use JS to automatically and continuously change a particular CSS property?

I want to create glowing border whose glow continuously brightens and dampens (using 3 properties to achieve this effect - border, box shadow, inset box shadow). How can I do so?

Please note that I am not talking about using "hover" or "active" states.
Also I want it to work in all browsers, if possible.

Comment: Show some work if you want people to help.

Comment: this is too broad of a question and a possible duplicate ... check here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165419/how-can-i-code-this-awesome-glowing-border-effect-with-css-and-javascript

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I have seen that thread before.
I am talking about a glow having a single colour. Also, I don't think it will require any image. (Please correct me if I am mistaken).

Comment: Both box shadow and inset box shadow are not available in IE8 and below via CSS. To be able to get it to work in "all" browsers, I'm assuming you mean to include IE8 and possibly IE7 as well. If that is the case, you likely will have to resort to using images to accomplish this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this has to be a JS solution, the following will work for you.

CSS:

```
#myGlower {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid transparent;    
    -webkit-transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
            transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
}

#myGlower.active {
    border-color: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}
```

And then using jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    var glower = $('#myGlower');
    window.setInterval(function() {  
        glower.toggleClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

You can see a [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xvGp/). While this is achievable using JS, you could also use CSS3 animations.

Also, you won't be able to get it to work in **all** browsers, as not all of them support the CSS properties that you mentioned (transitions, box shadow, etc.).

Comment: This is a good solution, but it does not support browsers < CSS3 in its current form.

Comment: Again, see his pre-requisite: 'border, box shadow, inset box shadow'. Come back when you have those working on browsers that don't support CSS3, please ;)

Comment: It's alright. This one looks good. Thanks a lot.  
By the way, could you please tell me the CSS3 only (and no JS) solution?

Comment: Sure, you can read about them here > http://www.zurb.com/article/221/css3-animation-will-rock-your-world

Comment: @gdebojyoti I hope you're using modernizr or something because CSS3 animations are only supported on ~60% of browsers...

Comment: @AlexW 60%?! Where did you get those stats from?

Comment: @Alex W: No, I am not. But since you have pointed it out, I'll have a look at it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't trust those stats so much, to be honest.

Comment: Those stats are roughly the same as StatCounter.com for the worldwide browser market share and the known feature support is just applied to browser usage stats, so they are actually quite accurate. For instance, IE9 doesn't support CSS3 animations which is roughly 17% of all browsers.

Comment: can someone post css only solution?

Answer (score 19):

Manipulating the above answer for CSS only solution

```
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    to {
         border-color: #69c800;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #69c800;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #69c800;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #69c800;
    }
}

.myGlower {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-animation: glow 1.0s infinite alternate;  
     -webkit-transition: border 1.0s linear, box-shadow 1.0s linear;
       -moz-transition: border 1.0s linear, box-shadow 1.0s linear;
            transition: border 1.0s linear, box-shadow 1.0s linear;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but not particularly relevant here, since the question specifically asked for a JS solution ;)

Comment: ok I needed it without JS so I posted it here instead of posting a new question. Hopes it saves someone's time.

Comment: better without js, before i would do it js because i didn't know css could do animations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to amend BenM's accepted answer in two respects. The first is to provide a pure JavaScript answer for those like myself who expected JS rather than JQUery from the question. The second is to provide a smoother animated glow, without the jerks in the example.

Two changes are need for a smoother animation: the border should be 0px, not 1px, and the transition should be on both classes, active and default (I've specified it as "passive"). In addition, using a value for spread size and a longer time for the transition gives a more subtle effect. I don't see any need to do a transition on the border.

```
#myGlower.passive 
{
    border: 0px solid transparent;    
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
    transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
}

#myGlower.active 
{
    border-color: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px blue;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px blue;
    /* in order: x offset, y offset, [blur size], [spread size], color */
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
    transition: box-shadow 2s linear;
}
```

For my animation I wanted to allow the user to set the animation to stop after a set number of cycles, or independently by user intervention. I also wanted the animation to stop in the non-glow state. The following code achieved that and can be modified to suit individual requirements.

```
    var done = false;       // flag to prevent resumption
    var timer;              // the setTimeout function
    var i = 0;              // counter - must be outside startMe()
    var limit = 0;          // number of times to repeat

    // call to start the animation
    function superStart(lim)
    {
        limit = lim;       // must set before startMe()
        startMe();
    }

    function startMe()
    {
        var glower = document.getElementById("myGlower");
        var currentClass = glower.className;
        if(done == false)
        {
            if(currentClass == "passive")
            {
                glower.className = "active";
            }
            else
            {
                glower.className = "passive";               
            }

            i++;

            timer = setTimeout(startMe, 1000);

            if(i >= limit)
            {
                stopMe();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glower.className = "passive";   // finish with glow off
        }
    }

    // separate function to also allow user action to terminate
    function stopMe()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        done = true;
        startMe();           // to start final cycle finishing in passive state
    }
```

I'm not actually sure if the clearTimeout() is required. (Works without it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use **Jquery**.

Pure Javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var glow = document.getElementById('myGlower');
setInternval(function(){
        if(i == 0)
            glow.setAttribute('class','myGlower');
    else
            glow.removeAttribute('class');
},1000);
```

Working Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/7xvGp/1215/](http://jsfiddle.net/7xvGp/1210/)

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the link. Thanks. or go here http://jsfiddle.net/7xvGp/1215/

Comment: setInternval should be setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery and CSS animation,

One CSS animation for the increase when you first hover, one for the changing glow, and one for the decrease when the mouse leaves the box.

(If you don't want to use the plugin, you can use other methods.)

```js
$('div.div').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('increase');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('div.div').removeClass("increase");
      $('div.div').addClass("glow");
    }, 1000);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('increase');
    $(this).removeClass('glow');
    $(this).addClass('fade');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('div.div').removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000);
  }
);
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}
div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
.increase {
  animation: increase 1s ease-in-out;
} 
.glow {
  animation: glow 5s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
} 
.fade {
  animation: fade 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes increase {
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
}
@keyframes glow {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
  25% { box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
  25%, 50% { box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
  50%, 75% { box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
  75%, 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from { box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

PS, I found out how to style the snippet 'console' when I was writing this:

```js
$('div').hover();
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid black;;
}
```