# Snake-Like Moving Glow around an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering how can you build a "snake like" effect around the rim of an object using javascript/css.

This effect will create an ever going animation around an object that looks like a tiny white slug moving on the rim of the object (looking like a glow)

(Will Edit this Question once I learn the correct phrasing)

Comment: Some inspiration: [Marching ants 1](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zm7Et/), [Marching Ants 2](http://playground.deaxon.com/css/rotating-dashed-border/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a small CSS3 version of this:

A small container and an our snake:

```
<div id="cont"></div>
<div class="snake"></div>
```

And here is the CSS Magic:

```css
#cont {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
.snake {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;        
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 15px;
    animation: around 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes around
{
    0% { left: 15px; top: 5px; }
    25% { left: 165px; top: 5px;  }
    50% { top:  160px; left: 165px; }
    75% { left: 15px; top: 160px; }
    100% { top: 5px; left: 15px; }
}
```

[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7DU/2/)

Comment: +1 nice and simple.  The demo doesn't have browser specific tags so may appear not to work in all browsers (safari for example)

Comment: @dc5, Yeah much simpler than other solutions proposed. I was lazy then to add browser specific tags, but since its a +1 answer now. I should honor that.

Comment: [improved version](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7DU/3/) with linear movement .-)

Answer (score 3):

Probably this might help

The code below moves a dot within the specified borders. Please see : that by adjust the width and height of the same dot you may have a snake like creature Have a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3PB8/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #midDiv{
            float:left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background:rgb(0,0,0);
        }
        #topDiv,#bottomDiv{
            float:left;
            width: 110px; 
            height:5px;
            background: red;
            position:relative;
        }
        #leftDiv, #rightDiv{
            width:5px;
            float:left;
            height: 100px;
            background: blue;
            position:relative;
        }
        #bodyWrapper{
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
        }
        #centerDiv{
            float:left;
        }
        .animateObject{
            z-index:2;
            background: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#topDiv").on("animcomplete", function(){
                $(".animateObject").remove();
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                $(div).width(5).height(5);
                div.className = "animateObject";
                $("#rightDiv").append(div);
                $(div).css({position: "absolute"});
                $(div).animate({
                    top: 100
                },
                2000, function(){
                    $("#rightDiv").trigger({type: "animcomplete", time: new Date() });
                });
            });
            $("#rightDiv").on("animcomplete", function(){
                $(".animateObject").remove();
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                $(div).width(5).height(5);
                div.className = "animateObject";
                $("#bottomDiv").append(div);
                $(div).css({position: "absolute", right: 0});
                $(div).animate({
                    right: 100
                },
                2000, function(){
                    $("#bottomDiv").trigger({type: "animcomplete", time: new Date() });
                });
            });
            $("#bottomDiv").on("animcomplete", function(){
                $(".animateObject").remove();
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                $(div).width(5).height(5);
                div.className = "animateObject";
                $("#leftDiv").append(div);
                $(div).css({position: "absolute", bottom: -5});
                $(div).animate({
                    bottom: 100
                },
                2000, function(){
                    $("#leftDiv").trigger({type: "animcomplete", time: new Date() });
                });
            });
            $("#leftDiv").on("animcomplete", function(){
                $(".animateObject").remove();
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                $(div).width(5).height(5);
                div.className = "animateObject";
                $("#topDiv").append(div);
                $(div).css({position: "absolute", left: 0});
                $(div).animate({
                    left: 105
                },
                2000, function(){
                    $("#topDiv").trigger({type: "animcomplete", time: new Date() });
                });
            });
            $("#topDiv").trigger({type: "animcomplete", time: new Date() });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bodyWrapper">
        <div id="topDiv"></div>
        <div id="centerDiv">
            <div id="leftDiv"></div>
            <div id="midDiv"></div>
            <div id="rightDiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomDiv"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

This moves a dot within the specified borders. Please see : that by adjust the width and height of the same dot you may have a snake like creature

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improvement on @Starx answer. I've made the `#snake` dimension-independent, and gave it a glow effect with box-shadow. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aQrkt/3/)

```html
<div id="cont">
    <div class="snake"></div>
</div>
```

```
#cont {
    /* some dimensions */
    position: relative;
}
.snake {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 15px red;
    animation: around 4s linear infinite,
               glow .7s alternate-reverse ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes around {
    0% { left: 0; top: 0; }
    25% { left: 100%; top:0;  }
    50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; }
    75% { left: 0; top: 100%; }
    100% { left: 0; top: 0; }
}
@keyframes glow {
    0% { opacity: .2; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

[Multiple snakes](http://jsfiddle.net/aQrkt/4/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hay after having a quick Google at javascript/css3 animaition.

have a look at this [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/10-crazy-effects-with-css3-border-transitions)

This previous question on stackoverflow deals with a border glow effect.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008931/animated-glowing-border-using-css-js link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008931/animated-glowing-border-using-css-js)

you could also uses a javascript animation library such as createjs .
http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS

Answer (score 0):

Create four images, that should exactly be a bit larger than the item, so when you look at it, the item is the foreground on a background that has "snaky" borders.

Create one with a fixed color. And make it "snaky" around the borders. Make sure it's a bit larger than the item itself.

The next image should be a different color, that is lighter, to create a glow effect.

The next image should be the color used in the first image, but exactly in the opposite fashion. All the crests in the first image must be troughs here ( To make it snaky ).

The fourth image again is same as the third, but with a lighter color.

Now, using JQuery, use "animate", and change the background of the item and cycle it between these four images in that order. This creates somewhat a "glow and crawl" effect.

You can extend this beyond four images, add more, to further the effects.